# Eigen: Mapping an array to matrix with matrix size unknown

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to read MNIST dataset with Eigen and each file represented by a matrix. I want the matrix size to be determined at runtime, since training set and testing have different sizes.

`Map<Matrix<uchar,rows,cols,RowMajor>> MNIST_dataset((uchar*)*_dataset);`

But get the following error:

```
NIST_Read.cpp:43:26: error: the value of 'rows' is not usable in a constant expression
     Map<Matrix<uchar,rows,cols,RowMajor>> MNIST_dataset((uchar*)*_dataset);
                      ^~~~
```

Can Eigen::Map be used in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would need to know what is `rows`, but if you want to use it as template parameter it must be a [`constexpr` variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) (or a macro of a literal integer, but let's not do that). However, you said you need to determine the matrix size at runtime, so you will need to use `Dynamic` as number or rows and specify the value in the constructor:

```
Map<Matrix<uchar,Dynamic,cols,RowMajor>> MNIST_dataset((uchar*)*_dataset, rows, cols);
```

Comment: Yes, I should use Dynamic here and it works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: @Mindong I'm glad it worked for you. If you think the answer solves your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).